# Change Formula Value through another Formula in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I want to change a value of a formula through another formula in Crystal Reports.

I have a problem: i have a string column in DB and is saved for example "Cars" or "Doors" or ..

and on the report i have all the categories written in Normal Textboxes. (Like a RadioButtonList).

and want if the Column is "cars" it will check next to the cars TextBox. (Like a RadioButtonList)

i thought that i make one Formula named `main_Categ` , and one formula next to each Category TextBox and i will write in the main_Categ Formula

```
if the Column = "cars" then CarsFormula="1"
else if the Column = "Doors" then DoorsFormula="1"
```

and so on .
what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be simpler just to have a formula for each checkbox. In each formula simply put: `{table.field}='doors'` for example. This will return true/false.

Your approach seems to introduce unneccessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Each formula MUST evaluate itself.

Create 2 formulas

CarsFormula  `{column} ="cars"`
and
DoorsFormula `{column}="doors"`